# Error: Invalid hook call. But can't understand where. React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

It's my firt time on react, and I'm trying to build a sign up form with steps. I read the documentation on material-ui and about ReactJS, but can't understand where I do mistakes.

I'll paste the error:
*"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See link for tips about how to debug and fix this problem."*

I think the error is in this two classes, but can't understand why or where.

FormUtentiPersonali.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


    const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
        root: {
            '& .MuiTextField-root': {
              margin: theme.spacing(1),
              width: '25ch',
            },
        },
    }));


export class FormUtentiPersonali extends Component {
    continue = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };
    back = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.prevStep();
    };
    render() {
        //const classes = useStyles();
        const {values,handleChange}=this.props;
        return (
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField 
                required 
                id="email-utente" 
                label="E-mail" 
                defaultValue={values.email}
                onChange={handleChange('email')}
                 />
                 <br/>
                 <TextField 
                required 
                id="password-utente" 
                label="Imposta password" 
                defaultValue={values.password}
                onChange={handleChange('password')}
                type="password"
                 />
                 <br/>
                 <TextField 
                required 
                id="conferma-password-utente" 
                label="Conferma password" 
                defaultValue={values.confermaPassword}
                onChange={handleChange('confermaPassword')}
                type="password"
                 />
                 <Button
                        label="Indietro"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={this.back}
                    >
                        Indietro
                        </Button>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <Button
                        label="Continua"
                        color="secondary"
                        variant="contained"
                        onClick={this.continue}
                    >
                        Continua
                        </Button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default FormUtentiPersonali;
```

FormUtentiAnagrafica.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


    const useStyles=makeStyles((theme)=>({
        root: {
            '& .MuiTextField-root': {
              margin: theme.spacing(1),
              width: '25ch',
            },
        },
    }));



export class FormUtenteAnagrafica extends Component {
    continue = e =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.nextStep();
    };

    render() {
        const giorni=[
            {
                value:'01',
                label:'01',
            },
            {
                value:'02',
                label:'02',
            },
            {
                value:'03',
                label:'03',
            },
            {
                value:'04',
                label:'04',
            },
            {
                value:'05',
                label:'05',
            },
            {
                value:'06',
                label:'06',
            },
            {
                value:'07',
                label:'07',
            },
            {
                value:'08',
                label:'08',
            },
            {
                value:'09',
                label:'09',
            },
            {
                value:'10',
                label:'10',
            },
            {
                value:'11',
                label:'11',
            },
            {
                value:'12',
                label:'12',
            },
            {
                value:'13',
                label:'13',
            },
            {
                value:'14',
                label:'14',
            },
            {
                value:'15',
                label:'15',
            },
            {
                value:'16',
                label:'16',
            },
            {
                value:'17',
                label:'17',
            },
            {
                value:'18',
                label:'18',
            },
            {
                value:'19',
                label:'19',
            },
            {
                value:'20',
                label:'20',
            },
            {
                value:'21',
                label:'21',
            },
            {
                value:'22',
                label:'22',
            },
            {
                value:'23',
                label:'23',
            },
            {
                value:'24',
                label:'24',
            },
            {
                value:'25',
                label:'25',
            },
            {
                value:'26',
                label:'26',
            },
            {
                value:'27',
                label:'27',
            },
            {
                value:'28',
                label:'28',
            },
            {
                value:'29',
                label:'29',
            },
            {
                value:'30',
                label:'30',
            },
            {
                value:'31',
                label:'31',
            },
        ];
        const mesi=[
            {
                value: 'Gen',
                label: 'Gen',
            },
            {
                value: 'Feb',
                label: 'Feb',
            },
            {
                value: 'Mar',
                label: 'Mar',
            },
            {
                value: 'Apr',
                label: 'Apr',
            },
            {
                value: 'Mag',
                label: 'Mag',
            },
            {
                value: 'Giu',
                label: 'Giu',
            },
            {
                value: 'Lug',
                label: 'Lug',
            },
            {
                value: 'Ago',
                label: 'Ago',
            },
            {
                value: 'Set',
                label: 'Set',
            },
            {
                value: 'Ott',
                label: 'Ott',
            },
            {
                value: 'Nov',
                label: 'Nov',
            },
            {
                value: 'Dic',
                label: 'Dic',
            },
        ]

        const {values,handleChange}=this.props;
        //const classes=useStyles();
        const [giorno,setGiorno]=React.useState('01');
        const [mese,setMese]=React.useState('Gen');
        const cambiaGiorno=event=>{
            setGiorno(event.target.value);
        };
        const cambiaMese=event=>{
            setMese(event.target.value);
        }
        return (
            <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
                <TextField
                required
                id="nome-utente"
                label="Inserisci nome"
                onChange={handleChange('nome')}
                defaultValue={values.nome}
                />
                <br/>
                <TextField
                required
                id="cognnome-utente"
                label="Inserisci cognome"
                onChange={handleChange('cognome')}
                defaultValue={values.cognome}
                />
                <br/>
                <TextField
                required
                id="numero-telefono-utente"
                label="Numero di telefono"
                onChange={handleChange('numeroDiTelefono')}
                defaultValue={values.numeroDiTelefono}
                />
                <br/>
                <TextField
                required
                id="giorno-nascita-utente"
                label="Giorno di nascita"
                value={giorno}
                onChange={handleChange('birthdayDay')}
                onChange={cambiaGiorno}
                >
                {giorni.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          </TextField>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <TextField
                required
                id="mese-nascita-utente"
                label="Mese di nascita"
                value={mese}
                onChange={handleChange('birthdayMonth')}
                onChange={cambiaMese}
                >
                {mesi.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
              {option.label}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
          </TextField>
          <br/>
          <TextField
          id="anno-nascita-utente"
          label="Anno di nascita"
          type="number"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true,
          }}
          onChange={handleChange('birthdayYear')}
          defaultValue={values.birthdayYear}
        />
        <br/>
        <Button
            label="Continua"
            color="secondary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={this.continue}
        >
            Continua
        </Button>
        </form>
        );
    }
}

export default FormUtenteAnagrafica;
```

Comment: Hooks are allowed in function component only. Suggested read is [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is a React hook which planned for functional components and you are creating `Class` components, So you can determine your state somewhere like `constructor` method. e.g:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
     super();

     this.state = {
       myVar1: myValue,
       myVar2: {id:1, title:'foo'}
     }
   }
   // ...
}
```

Then you can change your variables using `setState` method which inherits from `Component` class like this:

```
  <Button onClick={()=>this.setState({myVar: 'myValue'})} />
```

Please study first.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to React!

Some things that occurred to me straight off here.

React hooks such as `useState` cannot be used in class components, you will have to use a functional component. This is because the normal way you'd manipulate state in a class is defining a constructor and declaring a state object like so:

```
export default class App extends component {
 constructor(){
  props(){
   this.state = {
    //declare state items here
   }
  }

  render() {
   //render state and html here
   this.setState({}) //to update properties on the state
  }
 }
```

}

Like I said, if you want to use hooks, you must define a functional component and import useState from react.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
function App() {
 const [value, setValue] = useState('')
 return(
  //return things here
 )
}
```

I'd recommend looking at the react docs about hooks here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Hope this helps :)